# What does r option in Stata's regress command do?

Tags: regression, stata

I've seen the `,r` option used in Stata with the `regress` command:

```
. regress whora edad i.estudios i.cnae_4 i.sexo i.tipojor, r
```

However, I can't find that option in the documentation nor can I figure out what exactly it does. I can only see that it changes slightly the output by suppressing the sum of squares table.

Then, what does the `,r` option mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoever you're citing is using an older syntax, still supported. `r` is acceptable as an abbreviation for `robust`,  which in recent versions of Stata is documented as `vce(robust)`.

The use of robust standard errors is, however, utterly explicit in the default output. The consequence is in general different *t* statistics too, and different *P*-values, even if rounding hides either or both.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. regress mpg weight

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 72)        =    134.62
       Model |   1591.9902         1   1591.9902   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  851.469256        72  11.8259619   R-squared       =    0.6515
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.6467
       Total |  2443.45946        73  33.4720474   Root MSE        =    3.4389

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |  -.0060087   .0005179   -11.60   0.000    -.0070411   -.0049763
       _cons |   39.44028   1.614003    24.44   0.000     36.22283    42.65774
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. regress mpg weight, r

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =         74
                                                F(1, 72)          =     105.83
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.6515
                                                Root MSE          =     3.4389

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |  -.0060087   .0005841   -10.29   0.000     -.007173   -.0048443
       _cons |   39.44028    1.98832    19.84   0.000     35.47664    43.40393
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```